# Function for custom setter / getter Core Data

Tags: swift, function, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm trying to create a global function so my Core Data classes can use this function to create custom setters. But I'm getting `ambiguous use of 'willChangeValueForKey".

The code I'm using is:

```
func coredataSetter<T: NSManagedObject>(entity: T, attribute: CustomStringConvertible, value: String) {
    entity.willChangeValueForKey(attribute.description)
    entity.setPrimitiveValue(value, forKey: attribute.description)
    entity.didChangeValueForKey(attribute.description)
}
```

I'm kinda confused...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that reference is ambiguous. There's another implementation of `willChangeValueForKey` but your function declaration *should* clarify it.

Making this function generic isn't helping you in this case though. This function would be just as useful in a non-generic form which, fortunately, doesn't have the ambiguous reference problem. This version still handles both `NSManagedObject` instances and subclass instances:

```
func coredataSetter(entity: NSManagedObject, attribute: CustomStringConvertible, value: String) {
    entity.willChangeValueForKey(attribute.description)
    entity.setPrimitiveValue(value, forKey: attribute.description)
    entity.didChangeValueForKey(attribute.description)
}
```